# kubernetes service exposed to host ip

Tags: kubernetes

I created a kubernetes service something like this on my 4 node cluster:

```
kubectl expose deployment distcc-deploy --name=distccsvc --port=8080
 --target-port=3632 --type=LoadBalancer
```

The problem is how do I expose this service to an external ip. Without an external ip you can not ping or reach this service endpoint from outside network.

I am not sure if i need to change the kubedns or put some kind of changes.
Ideally I would like the service to be exposed on the host ip.
 Like http://localhost:32876

hypothetically let's say 
i have a 4 node vm on which i am running let's say nginx service. i expose it as a lodabalancer service. how can i access the nginx using this service from the vm ?

let's say the service name is nginxsvc is there a way i can do http://:8080. how will i get this here for my 4 node vm ?

Comment: Change the type parameter to NodePort. Your service will be listening on your nodes on a random port over 30k

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
so the requirement is i have a 4 node vm on which i am running let's say nginx service. i expose it as a lodabalancer service. how can i access the nginx using this service from the vm ?

let's say the service name is nginxsvc is there a way i can do http://:8080. how will i get this here for my 4 node vm ?

Comment: You either configure a port within the range '30000-32767' or you override the port via the below flag:

      --service-node-port-range portRange                       A port range to reserve for services with NodePort visibility. Example: '30000-32767'. Inclusive at both ends of the range. (default 30000-32767)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-apiserver/

Comment: i can change the service type to nodeport .. will that still be working as a load balancer ? i already have hotspot:true for my pods so i can access the individual pods using the housetop:port the idea is to add load balancing capability for all these hosts.

Comment: @Stock don't use hostport:true, nodeport is almost equivalent of hostport except it's guaranteed to be the same on all your nodes and you also get k8s loadbalancing (if you don't enable OnlyLocal)

Answer (score 1):

LoadBalancer does different things depending on where you deployed kubernetes. If you deployed on AWS (using kops or some other tool) it'll create an elastic load balancer to expose the service. If you deployed on GCP it'll do something similar - Google terminology escapes me at the moment. These are separate VMs in the cloud routing traffic to your service. If you're playing around in minikube LoadBalancer doesn't really do anything, it does a node port with the assumption that the user understands minikube isn't capable of providing a true load balancer.

LoadBalancer is supposed to expose your service via a brand new IP address. So this is what happens on the cloud providers, they requisition VMs with a separate public IP address (GCP gives a static address and AWS a DNS). NodePort will expose as a port on kubernetes node running the pod. This isn't a workable solution for a general deployment but works ok while developing.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
so the requirement is i have a 4 node vm on which i am running let's say nginx service. i expose it as a lodabalancer service. how can i access the nginx using this service from the vm ?

let's say the service name is nginxsvc is there a way i can do http://:8080. how will i get this here for my 4 node vm ?

Comment: This is too difficult to read. Where is your cluster deployed? What cloud provider?